# What does "Error in file.exists(pythonPath) : file name conversion problem -- name too long?" mean?

Tags: r, rstudio

I uninstalled and reinstalled R and RStudio. I installed R v.4.2.2 and RStudio 2022.12.0+353. And when I start a new R session or restart the session, I get that message with the error in the console.
Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot here.]

It doesn't seem to generate problems with my markdowns when I run the codes, but I'd like to know what this error means. I only use the R programming language, I don't use Python.

Comment: Check your `~/.Rprofile`, `./.Rprofile`, and/or `.rproj` file in your current project to see if there is a `pythonPath` defined. If none of those, perhaps this is a bug? I see many references to `pythonPath` in RStudio's IDE repo (https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/search?q=pythonPath), it seems convenient that it's the same spelling. Perhaps `Sys.getenv("RETICULATE_PYTHON")` could lend a clue?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have the same and nothing seems to work

Comment: @Antón I finished desinstalling that version and installed the previous one. So no, I couldn't solve it :(

Answer (score 44):

I had the same issue on windows 10 with Rstudio 2022.12.0 Build 353 with R 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt), and I solved it by unticking the "Automatically activate project-local Python environments" option that can be found by going to Tools > Global options... > Python".

[image: Python parameters menu in Tools > Global options...]

---

**Edit:** you may also add your favorite python interpreter, which, as expected, is also another way to solve this error.

I still have to test and play around to see if this will be useful for me, but you can even select a python from a specific conda environment as your default interpreter.

[image: Python parameters menu in Tools > Global options... example where an interpreter (conda) has been selected]

I won't get into what seems to be the recommended practices, but I found this [blog post by Posit on how to set and use Python in Rstudio](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/1500007929061-Using-Python-with-the-RStudio-IDE)

Comment: Thank you for your tip. Do you know what's the implication of unticking it? Can it causes problem down the road?

Comment: God it was that easy, it's solved, thanks a lot!

Comment: @MudWarrior My guess is that you will not be able to interpret any python code from your Rstudio, but then as you haven't had any interpreter selected, you wouldn't have been able to in any case... So no other implication except for removing the error(?)

Comment: Thank you very much! This fixed the following RStudio problems I had since last update.

 - Couldn't "Restart R" (Ctrl + Maj + F10): the process was never ending
 - Very slow RStudio launch 
 - Very slow Project closing, as well as
   switching from one project to another

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. What I did was to install Python on my computer and not forget to mark the "PATH" option:

[image]